# Why is the probability of $e^X \leq t$ the same as that of $X \leq \ln(t)$

Tags: probability

Why is the probability of $e^X \leq t$ the same as that of $X \leq \ln(t)$. We took the log of both sides here, but I think the result holds for any monotonic increasing function.

I know that applying a monotonic increasing function another monotonic increasing function results in a monotonically increasing function, but it's not intuitive to me why the probability of the above is equal.

Comment: They are exactly the same event; $e^X \le t$ is true in precisely the same outcomes as when $X \le \ln(t)$ is true.

Comment: You're calculating just probability of set $\{ \omega : e^{X(\omega)} \le t\}$ and it's just the same set as $\{\omega : X(\omega) \le \ln(t)\}$ due to ln function being 1-1 increasing

Comment: Check that is If $f$ is strictly monotone increasing, for any $a$ in the range of $f$ we have  $f^{-1}(\{y: y\leq a\})=\{x: f(x)\leq a\}=\{x:f^{-1}(f(x))\leq f^{-1}(a)\}=\{x:x\leq f^{-1}(a)\}$

Comment: @OliverDiaz Does it have to be "strictly" monotone increasing? What if you just multiplied by sides by a constant?

Comment: of $b>0$, $y=bx$ is strictly monotone increasing. If $f$ is just montonone nondecreasing, $\{x:x\leq b\}\subset \{x: f(x)\leq f(b)\}$ but the converse is not necessarily true. In the particular case at hasn't, $f(x)=exp(x)$, the conditions laid out in my comment above hold.